# Paid font on website

Tags: fonts

So another web bureau made a design for a website that I will code. The problem is that they used a non free custom font for all texts (not only headings). The font is Klavika.

What is the best way to tackle this? Should I just say we can't use it or should I just use @font-face or some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not concern you. Proper licensing of the font is responsibility of the client who ordered the site, you should notify them that the design uses a non-free font and that licensing should be arranged, but since you did not create the design, your obligation ends there.

Comment: I talked to my colleges and they said the same. It can be compared with non-free stock photos.

Answer (score 1):

If the license allows you to embed it on a website, then do so (unless the file size is huge). Otherwise, tell them it can't be done and to pick a different font.